# Using third party shell modules in Automator

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, automator

If I have a third party shell module installed, let's just say homebrew, and I have a run shell script block in Automator. If I now type a command that would just work fine in Terminal, what do I do in Automator? Let's say for example I have `brew install brightness`, it won't run in Automator

Comment: Automator (like AppleScript) uses a default shell, without any customizations, so you will need to source/include those, or just use full paths.

Comment: @red_menace I've now included the full path but it denies the access. Since I can't use sudo in Automator, what should I do about that?

Comment: Depending on exactly what you are trying to do, in current OSes such as Big Sur, any app you are using may need to be given accessibility permissions and/or full disk access.

Comment: @red_menace my Automator has full disc access and still says `permission denied`. By the way, how would my example from above look? Is `/usr/local/Homebrew install brew` correct since it doesn't even work in terminal.

Comment: If it is an app, may still need to give the Automator runner access - basically any executables that you are using.  I don’t use Homebrew, but it would be wherever it is installed, maybe `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: @red_menace the path to it is right, however the command doesn't seem to be working, even if I try sudo in Terminal. I'm not even trying to do this with this with this with Homebrew, I just thought I would ask the question with homebrew since it's more known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the entire path to the executable, in this case `/usr/local/bin/brew/`. Many if not all third-party shell utilities are in the directory `/usr/local/bin/`.